# Counting involutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, involutions

Suppose we have a group $G = H \rtimes K$, where $K = \langle \alpha \rangle$ is of order 2. We suppose that $K$ centralizes some 2-Sylow subgroup. Then every involution is of one of these forms:
1) $h \in H$,
2) $k$ a conjugate of $\alpha$,
3) $hk$ where $h$ is an involution in $H$ and $k$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$ centralizing it.

We want to count the number of involutions of type 3). Is there a way to do that if we know the number of involutions of type 1) and 2)? What about the number of conjugacy classes of involutions of type 3) if we know that all those of type 1) are conjugate? (Those of type 2) are conjugate by hypothesis).

Comment: Consider $D_4\cong\Bbb Z_4\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$, the dihedral group of a square. Its Sylow 2-subgroup is simply itself. The subgroup generated by a reflection does not centralize the whole group. In other words, the subgroup is not contained in $Z(D_4)$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't clear, that is a hypothesis

Comment: @hellotinfish I don't understand your comment. What are $G$, $H$ and $K$ in this example? What subgroup is not contained in $Z(D_4)$? It is part of the assumptions that $\alpha$ centralizes a Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are a bit late. The fact that $K$ centralizes some Sylow $2$-subgroup was made an assumption not long ago. See https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2533600/revisions